# how to place file inside /sbin/ in MAC 10.11 during .pkg installation

Tags: macos, mac, network, xcode

We have been installing / placing a tool for dhcp refresh under /sbin till MAC 10.10 there were no issues. but now it is completely blocked.
even with root privilege i cannot able to place it.
Any way is suggested?

Does Apple provide any other way to perform the release and renew IP address, clear the ARP entries in better way?

Thanks,
Saravana

Comment: /sbin/dhcp_refresh is not a default OS X utility.

Comment: But it was there when you just install Mac 10.x till Mac 10.10. Is there any other way to do my above expectations?

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/30/release-renew-dhcp-command-line-ipconfig/

Comment: Yes we are trying in that way as well but it is asking for elevated privilege. And is there any Api given by xcode or objective C which can dealt with it

Comment: Install in /usr/local/sbin would be the preferred way only Apple supplied programs should be in /sbin - Apple have now locked it with SIP so I very much doubt there is an API to allow you to add in SIP protected areas

Answer (score 1):

[wim-deblauwe's comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238694/how-to-place-file-inside-sbin-in-mac-10-11-during-pkg-installation#comment292791_238694) links to [Release & Renew DHCP from the Command Line with ipconfig](http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/30/release-renew-dhcp-command-line-ipconfig/) which shows how to do this:

> The basic syntax to renew DHCP lease from the command line with
>   ipconfig is as follows:
>
> ```
> sudo ipconfig set (DEVICEINTERFACE) DHCP
> ```
>
> If you know the device interface (en0, en1, en2, etc), just run that
>   command to release and then renew DHCP for the determined device.
>   Let’s say it’s en0, standard for modern Macs with wi-fi only.
>
> ```
> sudo ipconfig set en0 DHCP
> ```

Do not use [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) on OS X. This approach is considered a security risk and Apple appears to be working to invalidate any justification for it.

Any script or tool you create will need to acquire the appropriate [authorisation rights](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/) before calling the related API.